# Flag records in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Goal is to flag 1 record per `segment_code` where `Mtg_Flag = 1` if a record does not have `Mtg_Flag = 1` then flag the record with `Mtg_Flag = 0`. Code will flag all records with `Mtg_Flag = 1` to one but once this is run, how do you flag remaining records where `Mtg_Flag = 0`. My example has 153 distinct `segment_codes` and only 146 with `Mtg_Flag = 1`. So, how do I flag the remaining 7 `segment_codes` where `Mtg_Flag = 0`.

Code:

```
With LiveSam as (
Select acct_id,Row_Number() Over(Partition By Segment_Code Order By NewID())
    as      RowNumber
From Table_tr
Where LiveSam is NULL and seedrecordindicator is null and HasMtg_Flag = '1')

Update Table_tr 
Set LiveSam = 'Y'
From LiveSam L
Where Table_tr.acct_id = L.acct_id
    and L.RowNumber < 2
    and Table_tr.acct_id is not NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the CTE directly; you're trying to make the subsequent query far too complicated:

```
;WITH cte as -- don't call this a column name. Confusing.
(
  Select acct_id,Row_Number() Over
    (Partition By Segment_Code Order By NewID()) as RowNumber
  From Table_tr
  WHERE LiveSam is NULL 
  and acct_id IS NOT NULL
  and seedrecordindicator is null 
  and HasMtg_Flag = '1'
)
UPDATE cte 
Set LiveSam = 'Y'
Where RowNumber = 1;
```

I think this is what you need based on your query, but if you want people to follow your word problem accurately, please show some sample data before the update and the desired results after. I have no idea how you would ever expect to update rows where Mtg_Flag = 0 when you've eliminated those in the first place...

Comment: Yes it works. I took a step further by using variables to get the additional 7 records flagged. Thanks!